# Dell Inspiron 7537 wifi adpator disabled when lid closed

Tags: dell, power-management

I've just switched to Ubuntu 18.04 on my Dell laptop and I'm having an issue whenever I close the lid. The wifi adaptor is disabled and the PC requires a restart to enable it again. I've tried turning power management off for the adaptor without success and I've researched many threads with no luck. Any guidance would be appreciated. BTW I'm only semi-literate on linux/Ubuntu so pls be kind. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's unfortunate that this hardware incompatibility has forced me to abandon Ubuntu and return to Win10. Obviously a laptop that has to be restarted every time the lid is closed is a non-starter. I was impressed with Ubuntu 18.04 and I was able to find linux versions or replacements for 95% of my software needs. But the lack of support for this hardware incompatibility just doesn't work for me.